# Solve differential equation $yy''=2x(y')^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I can solve it when $y$ is not there on left-hand side. Not getting any approach how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

We can use $(\frac{y}{y'})'=\frac{y'^2-yy''}{y'^2}$.

$\frac{y'^2-yy''}{y'^2}=\frac{y'^2-2xy'^2}{y'^2}=1-2x$.

So $\frac{y}{y'}=x-x^2+c$ and $\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{x-x^2+c}$.

Now, $lny=\int \frac{1}{x-x^2+c_1} +c_2$

Comment: Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y\neq 0$. Let
$$ p=\ln y$$
and then
$$ p'=\frac{y'}{y}. $$
So
$$p''=\frac{y''y-(y')^2}{y^2}=\frac{2x(y')^2-(y')^2}{y^2}=(2x-1)\bigg(\frac{y'}{y}\bigg)^2=(2x-1)(p')^2. $$
and hence
$$ \frac{p''}{(p')^2}=2x-1. $$
Integrating both sides gives
$$ -\frac{1}{p'}=x^2-x+C. $$
You can do the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help